# Parâmetro dinâmico para plugin Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

Estou com a necessidade de enviar um parâmetro para o meu *plugin*, esse parâmetro é o caminho da pasta desse usuário.

Exemplo de variável:

```
$folder = /clientes/id_1/
$folder = /clintes/id_2/
$folder = /clientes/id_3/
```

Essas pastas são geradas automaticamente, cada cliente tem a sua própria, eis ai o meu problema, necessito enviar essa variável com o caminho da pasta para o meu *plugin* salvar isso em sessão mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.

Eu havia tentando uma requisição AJAX, direto ao arquivo raiz do meu plugin passando a variável `$folder` pelo método `GET`, mas não está dando certo.

Obs: não quero mexer nos arquivos do Woordpress/Woocommerce, preciso reaproveitar os `do_actions` dos próprios arquivos para poder manter as atualizações do Thema/WP.

Comment: Falta um pouco de contexto aqui: quem envia o parâmetro? como seu plugin está recebendo ele?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, eu não consegui encontrar uma solução mais viável do que enviar uma requisição para um segundo arquivo dentro do meu plugin(Quando eu enviava para o principal ele retornava um erro, então tentei enviar para um arquivo secundário sem nenhum vinculo com o principal), responsável apenas por setar a sessão.

Tenho certeza que não é a forma correta de se trabalhar, mas foi o que consegui fazer para resolver o meu problema...

Caso alguém saiba uma forma melhor para se fazer isso, fique a vontade para compartilhar o conhecimento.